# Priority pinning in apt-preferences with different versions and architectures

Tags: debian, apt

I'm asking this because I've lost too many hours figuring it out myself, the documentation is missing several important notes and I haven't found any other questions that really relate to this:

How do I prioritize specific package versions for multiple architectures? In particular, I have a number of different packages which I would like to download for multiple architectures, and I would like to prioritize the versions so that if they're not explicitly provided, apt will try to get a version matching my arbitrary requirements (in my case, the current git branch name) and fall back to the `develop` branch versions.

Eg. I would like to download package `my-package` for both `i386` and `amd64` architectures and I would like to pull the latest version that includes `my-git-branch-name` before falling back to the latest that includes `develop`.

Answer (score 6):

The official documentation is [here](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/apt/apt_preferences.5.en.html).

1. In order to support multiple architectures, all packages being pinned *must* have their architecture specified, and there must be an entry for each architecture. A pinning for the package name without the architecture specified will only influence the default (platform) architecture:

   ```
   Package: my-package
   Pin: version /your regex here/
   Pin-Priority: 1001
   ```
2. The entries are whitespace-sensitive, although no errors will be reported if you have whitespace. The following pinning will be silently disregarded:

   ```
   Package: my-package:amd64
       Pin: version /your regex here/
       Pin-Priority: 1001
   ```
3. `apt update` *must* be called **after** updating the preferences file in order for them to be respected and **after** adding additional architectures using (for example) `dpkg --add-architecture i386`

   The following excerpt from `/etc/apt/preferences` solves the stated problem:

   ```
   Package: my-package:amd64
   Pin: version /-my-git-branch-name-/
   Pin-Priority: 1001

   Package: my-package:i386
   Pin: version /-my-git-branch-name-/
   Pin-Priority: 1001

   Package: my-package:amd64
   Pin: version /-develop-/
   Pin-Priority: 900

   Package: my-package:i386
   Pin: version /-develop-/
   Pin-Priority: 900
   ```

Comment: For point 2 you said `The following pinning will be silently disregarded` why it will be disregarded? I don't understand.

Comment: If you look at the example in point 1, you'll see that all of the text is aligned left and there's no whitespace - no spaces or tabs - before any of the lines. In the example for point 2, the `Pin` and `Pin-Priority` lines are indented and that's why the pinning will be ignored, and it won't throw any warnings.